# C# math statement not working while doing it in parts works

Tags: c#, math

I am wondering if this could be some kind of associativity problem, because when I do the problem on paper, I get the correct answer, but when I run the code I keep getting 4 over and over. Here is the code. Why aren't these equal? What am I missing?

The whole problem (returns 4 on every iteration):

```
for (int x = 1; x <= stackCount; x++) {
            temp = ((x - 1) / stackCount * uBound) + lBound + 1;
            Base[x] = Top[x] = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(temp));
        }
```

Broken into pieces (runs correctly):

```
double temp, temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4;
        for (int x = 1; x <= stackCount; x++) {
            temp1 = (x - 1);
            temp2 = temp1 / stackCount;
            temp3 = temp2 * uBound;
            temp4 = temp3 + lBound + 1;
            Base[x] = Top[x] = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(temp4));
        }
```

Added:
Yes, I am sorry, I forgot about that declarations:

```
//the main memory for the application
    private string[] Memory;

    //arrays to keep track of the bottom and top of stacks
    private int[] Base;
    private int[] Top;

    //keep track of the upper and lower bounds and usable size
    private int LowerBound;
    private int UpperBound;
    private int usableSize;
```

I also think I had that backwards. I thought that if you used a double in a division operation with integers that the result would be a double, but it appears that is not the case. That makes sense! Thank you all!

Comment: are `stackCount`, `uBound` and `lBound` `ints` or `doubles`?

Comment: For the first code block, please show the declaration for `temp`. For both, please show the declaration of `stackCount`, `uBound` and `lBound` as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Speculation: `stackCount`, `uBound`, and `lBound` are all integers or longs.

Result: The entire expression is computed as though you're doing integer arithmetic.

Solution: `temp = ((double)(x -1) / stackCount * uBound) + lBound + 1;`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given us the full code. In particular, the declarations for `stackCount`, `uBound` and `lBound` and `temp` have all been omitted. You've also omitted the values of the first 3.

If, as seems likely, all the bits involved in your expression

```
((x - 1) / stackCount * uBound) + lBound + 1;
```

are *integral types*, the result will also be an integral type since integer division is performed:

```
int    x = 9 ;
int    y = 4 ;
double z = x / y ;
```

yields the expected double precision value `2.0`.

```
((5 - 1) / 9 * 11) + 3 + 1
```

The particular integral type that the expression resolves two is depends on the various types involved and whether or not they are signed, and whether or not they are all compatible.